# ¿Por qué me muestra este error Uncaught ReferenceError: Mercadopago is not defined?

Tags: javascript, mercadopago

Por favor me podrian ayudar con este error:

Implemente el `customized-checkout` de `mercadopago`

https://github.com/mercadopago/code-examples/blob/master/customized-checkout/basic-es.html

Pero en la consola de Google chrome me muestra este error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Mercadopago is not defined
>       at Function.Checkout.createDeviceProfile (checkout.js:1)
>       at checkout.js:1
>       at Object.success (checkout.js:1)
>       at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
>       at x (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)

Por favor necesito ayuda.

Comment: Este curso te será de utilidad: https://www.acamica.com/cursos/105/la-api-mercadolibre-conceptos-finales Saludos :D

Comment: y este otro también! https://www.acamica.com/cursos/62/introduccion-a-la-api-de-mercadolibre

Answer (score 0):

El origen del problema de costumbre es: o una llamada a una función que no existe, o que estás usando una variable indefinida en modo estricto.

```
"use strict";
  variable = 0;// Devuelve error porque está indefinida al no usar var anteriormente
  funcion();//Devuelve error porque no existe esa función
```

Asegúrate de no estar usando el modo estricto -si es así solo hay que borrar use strict- y de tener todas las funciones a las que llamas. Además, si no ves el fallo, también puede estar originado por un fallo en sintaxis como faltar símbolos como }, ", etc.

Espero que te sea útil

Answer (score 0):

En el ejemplo falta agregar un script, entre la carga del `jQuery` y `checkout.js` :

```
<script 
type="text/javascript"
 src="https://
secure.mlstatic.c
om/sdk/javascript/v1/
mercadopago.js"></script>
```

Espero te sirva o a alguien que caiga en el mismo problema, a la fecha de esto hace 3 años no cambian ese ejemplo.